# Numbering subsections with title before number

Tags: numbering

I am editing a tex document right now and I would need help to display the subsections in the opposite way to the usual. Just like here:[image: The example of output I want]

Comment: IMHO you do not search for subsections but for theorem environments. See, e.g., [packages like `amsthm`, `ntheorem` etc.](https://ctan.org/topic/maths-theorem).

Comment: Yes great thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.